# What's the right way to disallow crawlers by .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler

I've got my company (internal use) website indexed by Google when I've added such rule in the .htaccess:

```
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

robots.txt appear to be right by having one rule:

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /
```

Did I do wrong something?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AdsBot-Google [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AltaVista [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} BingPreview [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} spider [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bingbot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} DomainSONOCrawler [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} TelegramBot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Curl [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} WBSearchBot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp [OR]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mediapartners-Google [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot-Video [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot-News [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot-Image [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AdsBot-Google-Mobile [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} APIs-Google [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AdsBot-Google-Mobile-Apps [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} FeedFetcher-Google [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Google-Read-Aloud [OR]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
    #... more entries, not showing you the whole list
    # as it may contain false positives, find them yourself.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
    RewriteRule . - [F,L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Did you see the crawler read the robots.txt file? Seems it is ignored... Maybe the wrong file access rights?

Comment: robot.txt has 644.
Btw, In google documentation there is a section where they explain such kind of behaviours: If the page is referenced from another site, the robot.txt will be ignored and the spider is gonna considering the meta tag only (that was absent) 
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">